# Specman coverage: Is there a way to define ranges using variable?

Tags: range, cover, specman, e

I have `comp_value` that gets values between `1 .. 100`.
In addition I have an input variable `period` (of the same range). I need to cover 2 ranges of `comp_values`: `[1..period]` and `[period+1 .. 100]`. Something like this:

```
cover some_event_e is {
        item period using no_collect;
        item comp_val using no_collect,
            ranges = {
                range([1..period], "Smaller_than_period");
                range([period+1..100], "Bigger_than_period");
            };
    };
```

(The code causes compilation error since no variable can be written inside range).
Is there a way to collect the coverage?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: This doesn't make at all sense. Since period is something that varies, what do you expect to see for ranges smaller and larger than period?

Comment: There is different logic of DUT for comp_values bigger and smaller than period. I need to verify I've checked both of the cases.

Comment: Both comp_value and period are inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ranges must be constant.

But if I understood your intent correctly, you can define new items like

```
cover some_event_e is {
  item smaller_or_equal_than_period: bool = (comp_val in [1..period]) using 
    ignore = (not smaller_or_equal_than_period);
  item greater_than_period: bool = (comp_val in [(min(100,period+1)..100]) using
    ignore = (not greater_than_period); 
};
```

Assuming period is always in [1..100].